# How to create a master key on the master database?What are the roles required to GRANT to the login and user of the master db for the same?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, database-administration, azure-synapse

I am trying to create a master key on a master database of my azure sql datawarehouse. But my user does not have required permissions to do so. What are the roles need to be assigned/granted to the user or login of the azure sql datawarehouse? I was able to grant control permission using GUI of SSMS to the user of sql server instance on-prem. And also I was able to create a master key with the help of that role on master database of that sql server.The Scripts I used for that are:

```
CREATE LOGIN LoaderRC20 WITH PASSWORD = 'a123STRONGpassword!';
CREATE USER LoaderRC20 FOR LOGIN LoaderRC20;
ALTER ROLE dbmanager ADD MEMBER [LoaderRC20];
ALTER ROLE loginmanager ADD MEMBER [LoaderRC20];
ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER [LoaderRC20];
GRANT CONTROL ON DATABASE::[master] to LoaderRC20;
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '23987hxJ#KL95234nl0zBe';
```

But there's no direct provision to provide such access to the user on azure sql warehouse using GUI of SSMS.The scripts that I used for on-prem sql server instance are not working for azure sql datawarehouse.The GRANT CONTROL ON DATABASE::[master] to LoaderRC20; threw an error that cannot grant,deny or revoke permissions to yourself,sa,dbo,sys,etc. Is there any script to give permissions to azure sql datawarehouse's user of master db so that I am able to create a master key on it?If yes, then what are those scripts and their sequence?I have really tried hard to find answers to these questions. Please help me to find the answers

Comment: This was answered on dba.stackexchange.com https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/256411/how-to-create-a-master-key-on-the-master-databasewhat-are-the-roles-required-to

Answer (score 0):

Dbmanager is intended for creating databases and loginmanager to manage logins.

To create a master key (CREATE MASTER KEY) in Azure SQL just run the following statements on the user Azure SQL Database context not on the master database. If you try to create the master key on the master database you may run into error "Msg 15247". On the context of any user database you can try:

```
CREATE MASTER KEY 
GO
```

or

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD='MyPassw0rdIsComplex.'
GO
```